# How do I calculate the dsp address for a readwrite application in the beagleboard?

Tags: signal-processing, read-write, beagleboard

I'm trying to run the readwrite example in the dsplink on the beagleboard. To do so, I need to give the dsp address as a command line parameter. How do I know what is the dsp address?

I have the config file of OMAP5030. Here's a snapshot of the dsplink memory section diagram (copied from CFG_OMAP3530_SHMEM.c):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you must use readwrite, see [this](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php?title=DSP_MMU_Faults#If_you_know_the_memory_range_to_map_to_the_DSP_MMU_at_build_time_of_DSP).  You will want to look at .tcf files or such.  However, as mentioned by TI engineers, readwrite is a very dangerous example to use.  Look to MSGQ or other examples like that.